# uploading an image by url link

Tags: python, django

can you please tell me how to upload images via the url link through the django admin panel, not from my data warehouse, but via the url link

it is possible for me to download only from my storage, but how can I download from a url link ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can make it so that in the django administration panel you can add images by url link , and not by downloading a file